# Use my pc as a proxy server in restricted countries

Tags: proxy

I access the internet through the university wifi. I mean I don't have access to the router.
I want my family and friends to use my laptop as a proxy server (when my laptop is on) to access filtered websites in a restricted country.
How can I do it? and can they attack my laptop?
Remember that I can't go into the router settings. I saw some questions here, but they all have access to the router.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure about what you are asking.
If you want to access other websites that are region blocked, you can do that by connecting to a proxy server or with a VPN service.
 
If you are asking for a way to turn your own laptop into a proxy server, you need some web server skills to do that. You can find a tutorial on Lifehacker on how to [Bypass Heavy-Handed Web Filters with Your Own Proxy Server](http://lifehacker.com/5469038/bypass-heavy-handed-web-filters-with-your-own-proxy-server).
Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: My family is in a country that they can't access facebook,youtube,bbc, and some other websites. I want them to access these websites through my laptop, when my laptop is on.

Comment: Use a vpn service such as [CyberGhost](http://www.cyberghostvpn.com/en_us). But it also depends on your location. In what country are they located? A vpn is a great solution. You can try a free subscription first, to try if things work properly.

Comment: I am in USA, but my family is in Iran. Iran's government also has blocked some vpn services and proxy softwares, and if they work, they are so slow. It's hard to find a good vpn or proxy server.(they are also able to block vpn) I thought the best way that the government can't prevent it, is to have personal proxy server on my laptop, so my family can get to blocked websites through my laptop(which I don't have access to the router)

Comment: I think Hide My Ass! VPN still works in Iran. Anyway, read [How to Skip Internet Filtering in Iran](http://www.wikihow.com/Skip-Internet-Filtering-in-Iran) and [How to unblock Facebook in Iran / China / Pakistan?](http://anywhere.fm/en-vpn/unblock-facebook/). If you still are unable to access this sites, you can use [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) for this sites, and a normal browser for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

check this video to run a personal VPN service (SoftEther VPN)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVm3dMGu-B8

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just get a VPN? proxy are only meant for surfing, not essentially protections. Theres a bunch of deals as well going on for Christmas. Try PureVPN, it has [the best deal](https://www.purevpn.com/christmas-special) with 90% Off.